# fscanf() does not return correct data

Tags: c

This is a C project that implemented login logic, using `txt` file as a database.

Create a `users.txt` file and paste in the data, then run the code. When I am trying to login, I get "Login id or password is incorrect...", I think this is why `authenticated` = `0` and I believe the error comes from the core part of the login login where `if (valid_user_id) {...}`

The following codes is the login logic written in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void login_menu();

typedef struct {
    char user_id[6];
    char name[50];
    char password[50];
    char email[50];
    char role[50];
} users;

/* Main function */
int main() {
    login_menu();

    return 0; // return 0 to indicate successful execution
}

void login_menu() {
    title_printer("Login page");
    FILE *users_file = fopen("users.txt", "r");

    users user;
    int authenticated = 0;
    int login_attempts = 0;

    const int max_login_attempts = 3;

    while (login_attempts < max_login_attempts) {
        int valid_user_id = 0;
        char user_id[50];
        char password[50];

        printf("Please enter your User ID (TP number or Tutor code)  down below: \n");
        scanf("%s", user_id);
        printf("Please enter your password down below: \n");
        scanf("%s", password);

        if ((user_id[0] == 'T' && user_id[1] == 'P') || (user_id[0] == 't' && user_id[1] == 'p')) {
            valid_user_id = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                user_id[i] = user_id[i + 2];
            }
        } else if ((user_id[0] == 'T') || (user_id[0] == 't')) {
            valid_user_id = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                user_id[i] = user_id[i + 1];
            }
        } else if ((user_id[0] == 'A') || (user_id[0] == 'a')) {
            valid_user_id = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                user_id[i] = user_id[i + 1];
            }
        }

        if (valid_user_id) {
            // use while loop to read the file line by line
            while (fscanf(users_file, "%s;%s;%s;%s;%s", user.user_id, user.name, user.password, user.email, user.role) != EOF) {
                if (strcmp(user.user_id, user_id) == 0 && strcmp(user.password, password) == 0) {
                    printf("Login successful %s (%s) !\n", user.name, user.role);
                    fclose(users_file);
                    dashboard_menu(user);
                    authenticated = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (authenticated) {
            break;
        } else {
            login_attempts++;
            printf("Login id or password is incorrect, %d attempts left. Please try again.\n", (3 - login_attempts));
        }
    }

    if (!authenticated) {
        printf("Max login attempts reached. Exiting program.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fclose(users_file);
}
```

and the following is the users.txt file

```
988955;John;123456;admin@edu.my;admin;
265663;Mary;123456;marry@edu.my;tutor;
009650;Peter;123456;peter@edu.my;tutor;
544654;James;123456;james@edu.my;tutor;
577001;Johnny;123456;john@edu.my;tutor;
683357;David;123456;david@edu.my;tutor;
```

or try separating data using `space`, but I still got the same result

```
988955 John 123456 admin@edu.my admin 
265663 Mary 123456 marry@edu.my tutor 
009650 Peter 123456 peter@edu.my tutor 
544654 James 123456 james@edu.my tutor 
577001 Johnny 123456 john@edu.my tutor 
683357 David 123456 david@edu.my tutor
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Oops, I didn't read the question. Kindly post the whole code, and elaborate on *can't seem to be working*. How is it not working? How is it supposed to work?

Comment: With `fscanf(users_file, "%s....`, scanning into the 1st specifier does not stop because of `';'`.  Use a different format.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, what about using space ?

Comment: Using semicolons as the field separator is reasonable.  Using `%s` to read fields delimited by semicolons is not.  You need a negative scan set: `%[^;]` with lengths to prevent buffer overflows and you need to worry about newlines because scan sets`%[…]` and `%c` and `%n` do not skip white space, unlike all other conversion specifiers.

Comment: @JamesWong Post definition of `users`, a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

For starters, `char user_id[6];` is too small to hold the *string* `"988955"`, as it lacks room for the null-terminating byte. Use more generously sized buffers.

The primary problem is that the user ID validation (i.e., determining `valid_user_id`) will **never pass** for the example data set. All the shown user IDs are numeric, whereas the validation only tests for the case-insensitive *prefixes* of `"TP"`, `"T"`, and `"A"`.

You need to change the existing tests, or add another set of tests.

For numeric IDs consider something like:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

/* user id must only contain digits (minimum length 6) */
int is_numeric_id_valid(const char *id)
{
    size_t length = strlen(id);  
        
    if (length < 6)
        return 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if (!isdigit((unsigned char) id[i]))
            return 0; 
        
    return 1;
}
```

---

A secondary problem is that if the user's information is not found in the file, the file position indicator is left at the end of the file. Subsequent calls to `fscanf` will return `EOF`, so the second and third attempts at logging in will always fail, as no database entries will be read.

You must reposition the file position indicator to the start of the file after an unsuccessful attempt with `fseek` (or simply `rewind`). Alternatively, the file may be closed and reopened.

---

As for parsing:

Reading data with an unbounded `%s` specifier (e.g., `scanf("%s", user_id)`) is [as dangerous as using `gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2505965). You must limit the characters read to at most the size of the buffer minus one (e.g., `scanf("%49s", user_id)`), or risk invoking [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) when the buffer overflows.

As [@Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) points out, `%s` is not suitable for reading fields delimited by a semicolon, as it only stops when it reaches a whitespace character. It *could* work for fields delimited by whitespace, but then you lose the ability for your fields to contain whitespace.

The `%[` specifier can be used to read only the characters contained within a *set*. A `^` prefix within the set inverts this, reading only the character not contained within the set. Thus, `%63[^;];` reads *at most* 63 characters that are not the semicolon, and then attempts to match a semicolon.

As a point of opinion, the type name `users` to describe a *single* record is misleading. The singular `User`, or simply `struct user`, may be better.

Consider the following definition for your structure:

```
struct user {
    char id[64];
    char name[64];
    char password[64];
    char email[64];
    char role[64];
};
```

Instead of `fscanf`, if `fgets` is used to read a single line at a time from the database file, then `sscanf` can be used to parse that text.

Here we assume semicolon is used as the delimiter.

```
char line[512];

while (fgets(line, sizeof line, user_file)) {
    struct user entry;

    int res = sscanf(source, "%63[^;];%63[^;];%63[^;];%63[^;];%63[^;]",
                  entry.id, entry.name, entry.password, entry.email, entry.role);

    if (5 == res)
        /* line was parsed successfully */;
}
```

The return value of functions in the `scanf` family is the number of *conversions* successfully performed. You must always check this return value, or you will be operating with *indeterminate* values.

---

*Aside: you are effectively trying to parse [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). Depending on your requirements, you may want to find an existing CSV parsing library.*

---

Here is a more structured redesign of your program, that incorporates the examples discussed above.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct user {
    char id[64];
    char name[64];
    char password[64];
    char email[64];
    char role[64];
};

enum login_status {
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_FAILED,
    LOGIN_INVALID,
    LOGIN_ERROR
};

char *read_line(char *buf, int sz, FILE *f)
{
    char *res = fgets(buf, sz, f);

    if (res)
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;

    return res;
}

/* user id must only contain digits (minimum length 6) */
int is_numeric_id_valid(const struct user *usr)
{
    size_t length = strlen(usr->id);

    if (length < 6)
        return 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if (!isdigit((unsigned char) usr->id[i]))
            return 0;

    return 1;
}

int parse_entry(struct user *entry, const char *source)
{
    return 5 == sscanf(source, "%63[^;];%63[^;];%63[^;];%63[^;];%63[^;]",
            entry->id, entry->name, entry->password, entry->email, entry->role);
}

int user_auth(const struct user *target, const struct user *candidate)
{
    return (0 == strcmp(target->id, candidate->id))
        && (0 == strcmp(target->password, candidate->password));
}

enum login_status log_in(struct user *creds, const char *db_path)
{
    if (!is_numeric_id_valid(creds))
        return LOGIN_INVALID;

    FILE *users_file = fopen(db_path, "r");

    if (!users_file) {
        perror(db_path);
        return LOGIN_ERROR;
    }

    char line[512];
    enum login_status status = LOGIN_FAILED;

    while (read_line(line, sizeof line, users_file)) {
        struct user entry;

        if (parse_entry(&entry, line) && user_auth(&entry, creds)) {
            memset(entry.password, 0, sizeof entry.password);
            *creds = entry;
            status = LOGIN_SUCCESS;
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(users_file);

    return status;
}

int get_login_info(struct user *info)
{
    printf("Enter user ID: ");

    if (!read_line(info->id, sizeof info->id, stdin))
        return 0;

    printf("Enter password: ");
    if (!read_line(info->password, sizeof info->password, stdin))
        return 0;

    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct user info = { 0 };
    unsigned attempts = 3;

    while (1) {
        if (!get_login_info(&info)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read login info. Exiting.\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        switch (log_in(&info, "users.txt")) {
            case LOGIN_INVALID:
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid ID provided.\n");
                /* fall through */
            case LOGIN_FAILED:
                if (--attempts) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to log in. %u attempt(s) remaining.\n", attempts);
                } else {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Log in attempts exceeded. Exiting.\n");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                break;

            case LOGIN_ERROR:
                fprintf(stderr, "Internal error occured. Exiting.\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;

            case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
                printf("Success! Welcome %s.\n\tID: %s\n\tEmail: %s\n\tRole: %s\n",
                        info.name, info.id, info.email, info.role);
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
./login
Enter user ID: Johnny
Enter password: 654321
Invalid ID provided.
Failed to log in. 2 attempt(s) remaining.
Enter user ID: 577001
Enter password: 654321
Failed to log in. 1 attempt(s) remaining.
Enter user ID: 577001
Enter password: 123456
Success! Welcome Johnny.
    ID: 577001
    Email: john@edu.my
    Role: tutor
```

Comment: you are right `char user_id[6];` is too small to hold the value

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the login done by changing the following code, but if the user key in wrong answer 1st, and reenter a correct answer i twon work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void login_menu();


typedef struct {
    char user_id[50];
    char name[50];
    char password[50];
    char email[50];
    char role[50];
} users;

/* Main function */
int main() {
    login_menu();

    return 0; // return 0 to indicate successful execution
}

void login_menu() {
    title_printer("Login page");
    FILE *users_file = fopen("users.txt", "r");

    users user;
    int authenticated = 0;
    int login_attempts = 0;

    const int max_login_attempts = 3;

    while (login_attempts < max_login_attempts) {
        int valid_user_id = 0;
        char user_id[50];
        char password[50];

        printf("Please enter your User ID (TP number or Tutor code)  down below: \n");
        scanf("%s", user_id);
        printf("Please enter your password down below: \n");
        scanf("%s", password);

        if ((user_id[0] == 'T' && user_id[1] == 'P') || (user_id[0] == 't' && user_id[1] == 'p')) {
            valid_user_id = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                user_id[i] = user_id[i + 2];
            }
        } else if ((user_id[0] == 'T') || (user_id[0] == 't')) {
            valid_user_id = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                user_id[i] = user_id[i + 1];
            }
        } else if ((user_id[0] == 'A') || (user_id[0] == 'a')) {
            valid_user_id = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                user_id[i] = user_id[i + 1];
            }
        }

        if (valid_user_id) {
            // use while loop to read the file line by line
            while (fscanf(users_file, "%[^;];%[^;];%[^;];%[^;];%[^;];
", user.user_id, user.name, user.password, user.email, user.role) != EOF) {
                if (strcmp(user.user_id, user_id) == 0 && strcmp(user.password, password) == 0) {
                    printf("Login successful %s (%s) !\n", user.name, user.role);
                    fclose(users_file);
                    dashboard_menu(user);
                    authenticated = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (authenticated) {
            break;
        } else {
            login_attempts++;
            printf("Login id or password is incorrect, %d attempts left. Please try again.\n", (3 - login_attempts));
        }
    }

    if (!authenticated) {
        printf("Max login attempts reached. Exiting program.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fclose(users_file);
}
```

the data and the delimitation stay the same